# Can I set MainPageSuffix for my Google Cloud Storage without buying a domain name?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, web-hosting

Google Cloud documentation says that I can only set MainPageSuffix for my bucket after I verify my domain. But I don't need a domain, I only need MainPageSuffix to be set to index.html.

How can I do this without buying a domain name?

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#assign-pages
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/domain-name-verification#verification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is very simple. You cannot as this feature requires a domain name.

The technical reason is that enabling this feature requires a front end to Cloud Storage that processes the domain name and sets up the routing/forwarding rules.